# .SO library doesn`t work in unity android game

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, native

I work on an Android Game and want to use plugins.
 I installed **Visual-GDB** on Visual Studio 2015 and got a **.SO** file.

C code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "GDB.h"

int MyTestFunction(int x)
{
    return x * 2;
}
```

I putted the so file in **Assets/Plugins/Android/**
So I call the function in C# script:

```
[DllImport("libGDB-shared")]
public static extern int MyTestFunction(int x);

int res = 0;
void Start()
{
    res = MyTestFunction(3);
}
void OnGUI()
{
    GUILayout.TextField(res.ToString());
}
```

There were no problems in building process, but when I test it in my phone the TextField value is 0.

Comment: The .so file is compiled for your used android platform (e.g. ARMv7)?

Comment: @Robert Yes it is.